# A way to load different versions of ExtJs via RequireJS (AMD)

Tags: javascript, extjs, module, requirejs, js-amd

Old code uses deprecated ExtJs version (version 4.x).
New code should use ExtJs 5.x

I try to load ExtJs 5 on the same page where ExtJs 4 has been already loaded and used by some other JavaScript code.

I want to hide ExtJs 5 from the rest of the code. Something like:

```
define(["../../extjs-5.0.1/ext-all.js"], function (extjs) {
        //TODO use the "extjs" as link to Ext js global variable
});
```

ExtJs is not implemented as AMD module, so I cannot load it as described in the  previous example.

Can you please give me a workaround of the issue? Can I use some AMD-wrapper, that is a module itself, and returns "`Ext`" js variable that is defined in an  `ext-all.js` file.

Is there a way to reuse script that was written as regular JavaScript file (like ExtJs) as AMD - module?

UPDATED: I've read about shim section of RequireJS, here is what I try to do:

On a html page:

```
<script data-main="../js/configuration/skin/app" src="../requirejs/require-2.1.17.js"></script>
```

app.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../js',
    paths: {
        app: 'configuration/skin',
        extjs5: '../extjs-5.0.1/ext-all'
    },
    shim: {
        'extjs5': {
            exports: 'Ext'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['app/main']);
```

main.js file:

```
define(['extjs5'], function (extjs5) {
    //extjs5 is not nullable, it points to Ext variable
    // but Ext.getVersion() points to version 5
});
```

The problem now, the global Ext variable points to version 5. It may be a problem. I want global Ext js variable is not changed.

When I remove all extjs version 5 related steps, app.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../js',
    paths: {
        app: 'configuration/skin'
    }
});

requirejs(['app/main']);
```

main.js:

```
define(function () {
    // here I test Ext.getVersion() it points to version 4, not 5, as expected
});
```

In the last method Ext.getVersion() - refers to version 4 which is loaded as default for the page.

**How to use in my module ExtJs 5, and don't touch existing global Ext (version 4)?**